# osclass item validation mail is not received by user

Tags: osclass

I am using osclass. The item validation mail is not received by user but same mail received by admin.
Few days ago it was working properly but without any changes in coding or setting, now mail not received by user.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You email is probably caught by a spam filter. Ask the user to white list your domain name.